# How to position Overlay inside size of MediaQuery for Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, widget, tooltip, overlay, viewport

I use Overlay widget to impelment a tooltip with additional information for DataCell. The simple idea is when mouse pointer is moved to monitored MouseRegion the Overlay widget is displayed from left/top position which is returned by MouseEntryEvent. If space is enough than Overlay displayd well but sometime Overlay is out of viewport partially. How to implement automatic tracking of viewport size modification and setting correct starting point for overlay?

Comment: check `positionDependentBox` top level function - it could be used directly in `CustomSingleChildLayout`

Comment: @pskink, thank you for your answer. Didn't read/test it yet. Will test a little later. Hope there will be no unclear things.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` classes.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformTarget-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CompositedTransformFollower-class.html

1. Declare a `LayerLink` member variable. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/LayerLink-class.html
2. Wrap your DataCell with `CompositedTransformTarget` (supply it with your `LayerLink`).
3. Wrap your tooltip with `CompositedTransformFollower` (supply it with your `LayerLink`).
4. In your `OverlayEntry` builder you can use a `Positioned`. `LayerLink` will give you the offset of the target in `LayerLink.leader.offset`

Now the tooltip should be positioned relative to the target DataCell and should also move with the DataCell during scroll events or reorientations.